# C# - How do i guess a random number and then use it?

Tags: random

How do i make a random to an int to use it afterwards?
Error i get:
CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Random' to 'int'

```
        Console.Write("How old am i? Guess!");
        string randomguess = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("My age is " + (random.Next(1, 101)));
        int newrandomguess = Convert.ToInt32(randomguess);

        if(newrandomguess == random)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Oh you guessed my age correctly! Im surprised.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("As i expected, u guessed wrong..");
        }
```

Comment: you answered your own question ...

Comment: Random random = new Random();
this is above the first part of the code, forgot it

Answer (score 0):

To make a new random value:

```
int randomValue = random.Next(1, 101);
```

To use that random value to write out to the console:

```
Console.WriteLine("My age is " + randomValue);
```

To compare the guess against the value:

```
if (randomGuess == randomValue)
{
...
}
```

Comment: there comes an error doing this cause "randomvalue" is no int but a random

Comment: If you're using Random, then it should be. See this code sample: http://csharppad.com/gist/00f2c22f982081d27bd31f7a8fa3ba62

Comment: For your comparison, you must compare with randomValue, not random. randomValue is an int. random is a Random. That explains the exception you are encountering.